# Open complete key path in RegEdit

Tags: regedit

Is there a way to make RegEdit open SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager by pasting the key, instead of having to manually navigate the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137182/how-to-launch-windows-regedit-with-certain-path

Same question with quite good answers.